# How to find the array with the least differentiation to the other arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have to plot 10 lines,whose data are arrays of numbers.

For instance:

```
a1 = [100,88,20,30,50,35,32]
...
a10 = [90,80,30,35,52,45,12]
```

I want to find the line which can mostly represent all the lines. So i need to find the the array with the least differentiation to all the other arrays.

I don't know how to achieve this with python, especially with pandas or numpy etc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy. Try a simple least squares algorithm. Better yet, put them in a single Numpy array and compute a mean across the columns. That will best represent your array. If you want to not alter your values, compute median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you could calculate mean squared sum across all rows get the differencies for your rows with each of that value and find the minimum.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(632)
a = np.random.choice(range(100), (10, 10))
c = (a**2).mean(axis=1)
arr_ind = np.array([abs(sum(c - q)) for q in c]).argmin()
arr = a[arr_ind]

In [117]: a
Out[117]:
array([[46, 48, 58, 65, 44, 45, 72, 48, 84, 43],
       [97, 25, 72,  1, 95, 59, 84, 81, 12, 98],
       [33, 61, 36, 54,  2, 32, 44, 79, 90, 99],
       [60, 60, 36, 57, 93, 40, 61, 94, 60, 55],
       [39, 97, 49, 67, 60, 38, 80, 43, 29, 23],
       [59, 50, 57, 30, 62,  4, 28, 64, 15, 42],
       [91, 60, 80, 37, 98,  1, 34, 43, 81, 86],
       [39, 36,  5, 84, 73, 76, 87, 15, 82, 98],
       [74, 41, 76, 19,  2, 88, 30, 38, 93,  8],
       [71, 28, 78, 21, 83, 88, 61, 91, 34, 89]])

In [118]: arr
Out[118]: array([33, 61, 36, 54,  2, 32, 44, 79, 90, 99])
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what i want:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack (pseudocode):

```
arr_sum = numpy.argsort([numpy.sum(a) for a in [a1, a2, a3, ... a10]])
req_arr_id = arr_sum[4] # or 5, per your fancy.
```

`arr_sum` will have indexes sorted such that the sum of arrays is sorted. The index in the middle of `arr_sum` will denote that array with sum in the middle of all other arrays. This is not a statistically sound way of tackling this problem, but it is a quick hack.

For statistically sound solutions, run a least squares algorithm, or stack all arrays vertically and compute medians or means, like so:

```
stacked = numpy.stack([a1, a2, a3, ... a10])
medians = numpy.percentile(stacked, 50, axis=1)
means = numpy.mean(stacked, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define what you mean by "least differentiation to all the other arrays". But a simple definition would be "closest to the mean of all the other arrays, using a Euclidian norm." If that's what you want, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = [100,88,20,30,50,35,32]
a2 = [99,71,23,31,54,0,9]   # I added one to make it more interesting
a10 = [90,80,30,35,52,45,12]

A = np.array([a1, a2, a10])
mean = A.mean(axis=0)
dist_squared = np.sum((A - mean)**2, axis=1)
best = A[dist_squared.argmin(),:]
```